# Add user roles and map these with users

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am working on an authentication with ASP.NET Identify and Web API.

I have this code:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserModel userModel)
  {
     IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
     {
        UserName = userModel.UserName,            
     };

     var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);

     return result;
  }
```

In the AuthContext I added these roles with these lines of code:

```
Roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "User" });
Roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" });
Roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Superadmin" });
```

So now I need to know how to add one of these roles to a user. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to solve my problem.

I added the code of **SBurris** (thank you very much!)

```
_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userModel.Id, "User");
```

below the line

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);
```

But that is not the end: You have to insert the added role into the database into table **AspNetRole**. Now the application will start and function without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

The UserManager class has `AddToRoleAsync()`

```
_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userModel.Id, "User");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to add a role to a user with your code above. But I added an "await" before "_userManager". With this code I got into the Dispose method. Then I've tried it without the "await". I could successfull add an user to the database, but the role was not added.

Comment: How are you checking the role for a user?